# DBeaver spatial viewer different projection

Tags: dbeaver

I am trying to get the DBeaver (https://dbeaver.io/) spatial viewer to work and it works great with some data in 3857, but I have other data in local state coordinates (such as 2284 but others too).

DBeaver comes back with a blank grey screen, but a simple `SELECT st_transform(geom, 3857)  FROM geo_county` works and shows it spatially.

I do have the SRID on geo_county set to 2284 and DBeaver shows EPSG:2284 in the toolbar, and while switching that to 3857 shows me the map, it does so in China instead of the US.

Since DBeaver knows it's 2284, is there a way to add that, or tell DBeaver to always transform geom columns to 3857 so it will work in the table view without a query, or something else I'm missing?